# Loadrunner scripting

Tags: controller, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, vugen

If you dynamic value
Values :Performance,tester,role ??
And this 3 values changing there places on every iteration how can be capture all three things using loadrunner .
In this question LB : Values :
RB: ??
How can I capture Performance,tester,role

If this are always changing there positions like (tester, Performance,role) or (role, performance, tester)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us about your training in LoadRunner